# How do I specify an optional trailing character in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to match either **W** or **W*** in a grammar. Here's a stripped-down version:

```
grammar PdfStream;

content : stat* ;

stat
     : wCap ;

wCap: 'W' '*'? ; // Set clipping path using nonzero winding ('W') or even-odd ('W*') rule

// Accept all characters except whitespace and defined delimiters ()<>[]{}/%
ID: ~[ \t\r\n\u000C\u0000()<>[\]{}/%]+ ;

WS: [ \t\r\n\u000C\u0000]+ -> skip ; // PDF defines six whitespace characters
```

When I try it with this input:

> W W* W

my visitor gets the first **W** but nothing after that.

But if I use this definition instead:

```
wCap: ('W'|'W*') ;
```

the visitor gets all three statements.

That's a workable solution but I'm curious as to why my first definition doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antlr lexer rules prefer longest match and then break ties by taking the rule defined first.

To make things clearer, lets move the implicit tokens `'W'` and `'*'` into named lexer rules because this is internally what antlr is doing. I'll call them `DUB_U` and `STAR` to try and avoid confusion when referring to the rule vs the characters. Hence your lexer is really:

```
DUB_U: 'W' ;
STAR: '*' ;
ID: ~[ \t\r\n\u000C\u0000()<>[\]{}/%]+ ;
WS: [ \t\r\n\u000C\u0000]+ -> skip ;
```

When matching `W W* W` you get the token stream:

```
DUB_U(W) WS( ) ID(W*) WS( ) DUB_U(W)
```

This is because `W*` matches `ID` and it is longer than simply matching `W` from `DUB_U`.

When you change the rule to `wCap: ('W'|'W*') ;` your new effective lexer is:

```
DUB_U: 'W' ;
DUB_U_STAR: 'W*' ;
ID: ~[ \t\r\n\u000C\u0000()<>[\]{}/%]+ ;
WS: [ \t\r\n\u000C\u0000]+ -> skip ;
```

When matching `W W* W` you get the token stream:

```
DUB_U(W) WS( ) DUB_U_STAR(W*) WS( ) DUB_U(W)
```

This is because `W*` matches **both** `DUB_U_STAR` and `ID`, but `DUB_U_STAR` is defined first and the tiebreaker makes a `DUB_U_STAR` token.